# How to Make Bootstrap 3 Columns Wrap Content on Larger Devices?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I'm basically trying to build a navbar (I don't want to use the Bootstrap navbar), and on phones (`xs`) I want the individual items to be full width, but on all larger devices I just want them to flow naturally.

Right now I have this, which obviously would **set** the widths on all but `xs` devices, but that doesn't look natural for text.

```html
<div class="row header">
    <a href="/creations"><div class="col-sm-2 bar-col">
        Creations
    </div></a>
    <a href="/blog"><div class="col-sm-2 bar-col">
        Blog
    </div></a>
    <a href="/teaching"><div class="col-sm-2 bar-col">
        Teaching
    </div></a>
</div>
```

Is there a Bootstrap way to do this? What's the best way to do this? I have been considering just ditching the Bootstrap stuff here and going with `@media` queries to make this happen. Should I go for it?

Comment: Don't forget if you do use your own media queries that you can use the Bootstrap variable to specify the device size: `@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ended up being not that hard, and I even worked it together with Bootstrap.

```html
<div class="row header">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="row">
            <a href="/creations"><div class="col-xs-12 bar-col text-nav">
                Creations
            </div></a>
            <a href="/blog"><div class="col-xs-12 bar-col text-nav">
                Blog
            </div></a>
            <a href="/teaching"><div class="col-xs-12 bar-col text-nav">
                Teaching
            </div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    .text-nav {
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

Simple! The `col-xs-12` handles the case of small devices, and the behavior is overwritten for larger devices.

Comment: there are 3 opening divs and 6 closing divs in this html part... also, a closing div inside an anchor tag seems to be an error.

Answer (score 2):

I would use @media queries, I've never had a problem with them and they are easy to grasp, especially if you know how to do them which I'm guessing you do due to the fact you mentioned them.

Oh and if you look at bootstrap.css it uses @media queries itself as this is the "built in" responsive part of the css...

Hope this helps.